# Lost MacBook's last detected location

Tags: find-my-iphone, find-my-mac

I received notification that Find iPhone's remote erase had been started on my lost MacBook on a specific time. I suppose someone brought it online, Apple detected it and initialized the remote wipe request I had set up. Somehow It's not showing the last location, which is weird to me. Any idea why last location is not shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. Although Find iPhone app doesn't give any clue, this feature on www.icloud.com does explain it: "The location of this Mac won't be updated because it has been erased.". Looks like the behaviour is part of the product design, rationale behind the design is unclear though.